# What wrong memory am I accessing which is causing segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, mergesort

Having Segmentation Fault on the following code of counting inversions in an array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits.h>
using namespace std;

int merge(int *a, int p, int q, int r);

int mergesort(int *a, int p, int r) {
    if (p < r) {
        int q = (p + r) / 2;
        //Dividing the array in two.
        int l = mergesort(a, p, q);
        int r = mergesort(a, q + 1, r);
        int cross = merge(a, p, q, r);
        return (l + r + cross);
    } else
        return 0;
}
```

This was the `mergesort` function supposed to divide the array. Doesn't seem to have an error here.

```
int merge(int *a, int p, int q, int r) {
    int inv_count =0;
    int n1 = q - p + 1, n2 = r - q;

    int L[n1 + 1], R[n2 + 1];
    //Two subarrays with last elements as inf.
    L[n1] = INT_MAX; R[n2] = INT_MAX;

    for (int i = p, j = 0; j < n1; i++, j++) L[j] = a[i];//copy left
    for (int i = q + 1, j = 0; j < n2; i++, j++) R[j] = a[i];//copy right

    int i = 0, j = 0, k = p;//merge and count
    while (k <= r) {
        if (L[i] <= R[j]) {
            a[k++] = L[i];
            i++;
        } else {
            a[k++] = R[j];
            inv_count += n2 - j + 1;
            j++;
        }
    }
    return inv_count;
}
```

The problem maybe seems to have in the above function where I have declared the `L` and the `R` array.

```
int main() {
    //code
    int n; cin >> n;
    int a[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) cin >> a[i];
    cout << mergesort(a, 0, n - 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Example input: `5 5 4 3 2 1` shows `Seg Fault`.

Comment: Isn't merge sort supposed to have 3 values only?

Comment: `int a[n];` is not standard c++. Use `std::vector` for dynamically sized arrays

Comment: used ```int *a =new int[n]``` still having seg fault.

Comment: and still `std::vector` is the better alternative because it has a `at` method that can tell you exactly where you go out of bounds without any additional effort from your side

Comment: if you stay with a c-array you would basically have to emulate what `at` already does for you: check every access and raise an error/exception when it goes out of bounds

Comment: The debugger can tell you which line in your code has the segfault.  I suspect it will be in that `while` loop in `merge`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `mergesort`, you have a shadowing problem:

```cpp
int r = mergesort(a,q+1,r);
                        ^
```

The `r` argument passed isn't the `r` declared in the function, it's the `r` you just declared. That's undefined behavior.

By "print debugging" `merge` with the code:

```cpp
int merge(int *a, int p, int q, int r) {
  int inv_count = 0;
  int n1 = q - p + 1, n2 = r - q;
  std::cout << "merge(a, " << p << ", " << q << ", " << r << ')'<< std::endl;
  std::cout << "\tsize of L: " << (n1 + 1) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "\tsize of R: " << (n2 + 1) << std::endl;
  (...)
```

I got the output:

```
merge(a, 0, 0, 0)
    size of L: 2
    size of R: 1
merge(a, 0, 1, 0)
    size of L: 3
    size of R: 0
merge(a, 0, 2, 0)
    size of L: 4
    size of R: -1
```

The segfault happens when you try to create an array with negative size. Notice the `r` parameter passed to merge, it's because of that first problem.

Comment: Also, there is an issue with input argument checking. If `p` and `r` are 0, then the line `int r = mergesort(a,q+1,r)` tries to access element at position 1.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in the code:

- `int r = mergesort(a, q + 1, r);` redefines `r` and passes an uninitialized value to `mergesort` instead of the argument `r`. Use a different variable name such as:

  int nr = mergesort(a, q + 1, r);
- `L[n1] = INT_MAX; R[n2] = INT_MAX;` using *sentinel* values to avoid testing the index values in the merge phase is a common but nefarious example in some textbooks. The algorithm will fail if the array contains entries with the value `INT_MAX`, which is possible with the `main()` function provided. Don't use this silly approach and test the index values.
- `cout << mergesort(a, 0, n - 1);` Passing the index to the last element of the slice leads to cumbersome code with non-intuitive `+ 1` and `- 1` adjustments. Furthermore it does not allow passing empty slices. Passing the index of the first excluded element is more idiomatic in C and C++ and simplifies the code.
- `int q = (p + r) / 2;` This expression can overflow and produce an incorrect value for `q`. It should be written: `int q = p + (r - p) / 2;`
- index values should have type `size_t`.

Here is a modified version for small values of `n`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

size_t merge(int *a, size_t p, size_t q, size_t r) {
    size_t inv_count = 0;
    size_t n1 = q - p, n2 = r - q;

    int L[n1], R[n2];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n1; i++) L[i] = a[p + i];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n2; i++) R[i] = a[q + i];

    size_t i = 0, j = 0, k = p; //merge and count
    while (k <= r) {
        if (i < n1 && (j == n2 || L[i] <= R[j])) {
            a[k++] = L[i];
            i++;
        } else {
            a[k++] = R[j];
            inv_count += n2 - j + 1;
            j++;
        }
    }
    return inv_count;
}

size_t mergesort(int *a, size_t p, size_t r) {
    if (r - p > 1) {
        size_t q = p + (r - p) / 2;
        // Dividing the array in two.
        size_t nl = mergesort(a, p, q);
        size_t nr = mergesort(a, q, r);
        size_t cross = merge(a, p, q, r);
        return nl + nr + cross;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main() {
    size_t n; cin >> n;
    int a[n];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) cin >> a[i];
    cout << mergesort(a, 0, n);
    return 0;
}
```